# Trouble copying text file into Excel using VBA

Tags: debugging, excel, copy, text-files, vba

I want to copy contents from text file to an Excel cell using VBA. I can do this succesfully from most text files. But in case of certain files, the code is copying only partial data into the excel file.

This is the code I used for copying

> ```
> FileName = folderpath & sFile
> Set mytextfile = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
> mytextfile.Sheets(1).Cells.CurrentRegion.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & inputRow)
> 'mytextfile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & inputRow)
> mytextfile.Close (False)
> ```

I already understand what is the problem. While opening certain text files as excel files, some contents are present in cell A1 and the rest in cell A2.

I don't know why it is opened so. I am posting contents of two text file below:

1)Text file whose contents are contained in different cells when opened in excel

> fwi!3F5A!041!g1ksIpqub7J MCMILLAN J. PIIKKILA RAYMONDBERRY@WEBTV.NET
>   +001 061 477 130 F g3ktHqrwc9 CLE!g1ksIpqub7 CLEHS04C |P.O. BOX 171 SEARSPORT,ME Nashville 68800 AZ| |5150 CTY RD 525 Raleigh 64292|
>   18000000 0412CL0 1 N 2

I got the following output when I used the above text file.

> fwi!3F5A!041!g1ksIpqub7J MCMILLAN J. PIIKKILA RAYMONDBERRY@WEBTV.NET +001 061 477 130 F g3ktHqrwc9 CLE!g1ksIpqub7 CLEHS04C |P.O. BOX 171 SEARSPORT

2)Text file whose contents are contained in a single cell A1

> fSj!3U68!071!gQloo3d5OGG Presley Y. TART JR PULPACTION82@HOIMAIL.COM
>   +001 047 475273 M gQmqq6d8ME CVE!gQloo3d5OG CVEGF07C |10001 SW 125TH CT RD Reno 88595 TN| |10849 DEBORAH DRIVE Glendale 70958| 97400000
>   0712CV0 0 N 0

I got the following output when I used the above text file.

> fSj!3U68!071!gQloo3d5OGG Presley Y. TART JR PULPACTION82@HOIMAIL.COM +001 047 475273 M gQmqq6d8ME CVE!gQloo3d5OG CVEGF07C |10001 SW 125TH CT RD Reno 88595 TN| |10849 DEBORAH DRIVE Glendale 70958| 97400000 0712CV0 0 N 0

There is no apparent difference between the contents of these two file.

I also tried this code but without any success:

```
FileName = folderpath & sFile
Set mytextfile = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
mytextfile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & inputRow)
mytextfile.Close (False)
```

Comment: Where does the partial data stop? Please include the output of the failure, and what you've tried (if anything) to debug it (for instance, changing the character it freezes on, making sure there are no hidden ascii characters, etc.).

Comment: @jmac I updated the question to include the outputs I got. I referred many sites and all say just to copy the content of cell A1 to get the entire text file in excel. This seemed okay for about 50 files but not for 3 other files.

Comment: If you copy-paste the text from this question (for the broken entry) back in to a text file, could you see if it works? I don't know how the text files are generated, but it is possible there is a hidden character in the file causing trouble, or otherwise mucking things up. Copying plain text back in may make it work (or at least eliminate one possible reason).

Comment: I also really suggest changing the e-mail addresses/password hashes there if they are actually from customers. (the issue is not occurring there, so changing them shouldn't alter the result)

Comment: Since it's hanging on a comma, there is a good possibility that what's happening is Excel is guessing that your text file is CSV (comma-separated value) file when it opens it, and automatically moving the last half to cell B1 instead. Try opening the text file in Excel manually, and see if that is happening.

Comment: @jmac Yes I think you have a point there about csv. I tried to open the file manually using Excel. But when I do so, many options are coming on how to open the text file.

Comment: If so, [this question on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text) may help. You can try setting the `Open` options to treat it as text and not delimit.

Comment: @jmac But I am trying to open a text file not a .csv file.

Comment: I think the error is in this line:  Workbooks.Open(FileName)

Comment: @Foreever is my answer not helpful to you?

Comment: @mehow It is helpful. I was trying to integrate your code with mine.

Comment: @Foreever so where are you still having problems?

Comment: @mehow I posted it as comment to your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem:

You are not using the right approach to read a `*.txt` file in VBA. Opening file using `Workbooks.Open()` treats the opened file as a [`*.csv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Therefore, when Excel is reading a stream and a comma occurs it treats it as a *new line separator* and throws the remaining part (*after the comma*) to the next cell. As stated on [MSDN Workbooks.Open Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819.aspx)

> expression .Open(FileName ... )
>
> **expression** A variable that represents a **Workbooks object.**

Clearly, a `Workbook object` not a `txt` file.

---

## Solution:

The right approach to read content of a `*.txt` file is to use the `FileSystemObject` and `TextStream` objects from the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` Library.

I wrote a simple `Sub` for you that reads the entire content of a `*.txt` file. In order to make it work you have to add references to your project

In VBE window, click `Tools` » `References` » *scroll down, find, and tick* `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Now, screen through the below code and modify the path to your `*.txt` file or pass the path through a parameter and the entire content of your `*.txt` file will be placed in the first Sheet *`Sheet(1)`* Cell `A1`

```
Sub ReadTxtFile()

    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFS As TextStream
    
    Dim fileName As String
    ' make sure to update your path or
    ' pass it to the sub through parameter
    fileName = "C:\Users\fooboo\Desktop\text.txt"
    
    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(fileName)
    
    Dim content As String
    content = oFS.ReadAll
    
    With Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = content
    End With
    
    oFS.Close
    Set oFS = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @Foreever glad I could help. here on stackoverflow, we say thank you by upvoting and accepting answers (*green check mark top-left of the answer*).

Comment: Why are these characters 'ï»¿' before each copied text?

Comment: I was going to accept your answer. I was just checking whether the code worked perfect. You need to be little more patient :P

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean about the `'ï»¿'` characters? Where are they? What text are you copying. The code works perfect I have already checked it using your sample input and output :)

Comment: This is the output I got after using your code:<br/>  ï»¿fwi!3F5A!041!g1ksIpqub7J MCMILLAN J. PIIKKILA RAYMONDBERRY@WEBTV.NET +001 061 477 130 F g3ktHqrwc9 CLE!g1ksIpqub7 CLEHS04C |P.O. BOX 171 SEARSPORT,ME Nashville 68800 AZ| |5150 CTY RD 525 Raleigh 64292| 18000000 0412CL0 1 N 2

Comment: Can you open the txt file manually and confirm that there is no other characters before the word `fwi!`?

Comment: You see in the output three characters appear from nowhere. I can easily remove it using string functions. Just curious where it come from.

Comment: it comes from the text file itself, the TextStream is deifnitely **not** adding it if that's what you are asking

Comment: I opened the file manually. There is no such characters originally. It's OK. I'm really thankful for your help. I wonder what you get for these. Any benefit from 'Stackoverflow'

Comment: @Foreever add a `.ClearContents` line below the `.NumberFormat = "@"`, see updated code in the answer.

Comment: While executing the code,excel is crashing. Using break point,I found out that cashing occurs right after executing  last 'End Sub' in the code.

Comment: @Foreever try adding `Set oFSO = Nothing` before the `End Sub`. I honestly dont think the crashing is related to this code...

Comment: @mehow  It somehow got running successfully after a while. Thank your for your help though.